# Cannot explicitly refer to controls on a report (MS Access/VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

How do I refer to a report's controls explicitly?  Referring implicitly works as expected:

```
Me.lblTest.Visible = True
```

However, all of my attempts at referencing the control *explicitly* meet with various nonsensical runtime errors.  Access' favorite:

> "The report name 'rptTest' you entered is misspelled *(it's not)* or refers to a report that isn't open *(it is)* or doesn't exist *(it does)*."

I've tried a dozen syntax variations from MSDN and everywhere else I could find, all producing errors:

```
Reports!rptTest.lblTest.Visible = True
    ' ^--expected syntax, like Forms!frmName.ctlName.Property
Reports!("rptTest").lblTest.Visible = True
Reports![rptTest].lblTest.Visible = True
Reports("rptTest").Controls("lblTest").Visible = True
etc. etc.
```

This should be no different from referring to forms' controls, right?  There must be a way to refer explicitly to a report's controls.

Comment: What happens when you try `Reports!rptTest!lblTest.Visible = True`?  If there is an error, what is the full text of the error message for that one?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It gives the exact same error, minus my flustered parentheticals, as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the names of the reports Access thinks are open.

With your report open, go to the Immediate window.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you there.

Paste in `for each rpt in reports : ? rpt.name : next` as one line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Access will tell you the names of the open reports as it sees them.

Here is an Immediate window example from my system with one report, *rptFoo*, open ...

```vb
for each rpt in reports : ? rpt.name : next
rptFoo
```

The problem you're facing is that *rptTest* is open, but Access disagrees.  That discrepancy can be caused at least 3 ways:

1. *rptTest* is what you see when the report is open, but that is the report's `Caption` property instead of its `Name`
2. *rptTest* is a subreport contained in some other open report.  The `Reports` collection, which is where Access looks to find open reports, contains only the "top-level" reports which are open. If you're dealing with a subreport, reference it via its parent report ... `Reports!rptParent!SubreportControl!lblTest.Visible` where `SubreportControl` is the name of the subreport control which contains *rptTest*.  Be careful because the name of that subreport control may not be *rptTest* --- you need the name of the subreport control, not the name of the report it contains.
3. If *rptTest* is contained in a subform/subreport control within a form (instead of within a report), the situation is similar to #2, but you must reference it via its parent form ... `Forms!YourFormName!SubcontrolName!lblTest.Visible`

Comment: Thanks, but I've never used the Immediate window.  I entered what you advised into it, but I can't figure out how to make it do anything.  MSDN doesn't seem to explain how to run whatever's in it.

I should also mention that I'm attempting to reference the Report's controls through a subform control on a parent Form.

Comment: I'm not sure what you said, but it sounds like you got to the Immediate window.  From there, paste in `? Reports.Count` and press Enter.  What number does Access show you for `Count`?

Comment: It shows '1', which I would expect, but the For... line you gave above does nothing.  I am viewing the Report through a subform/subreport control within a Form.

Comment: OK, Access believes there is one "top-level" report open.  Try the `for each rpt ... ` statement again, making sure to press Enter at the end of that line.  Then on the next line Access should show you the name it recognizes for the open report.  What is that name?

Comment: The `for each rpt ...` in Immediate still returns nothing (it auto-capitalizes `For`, so it's obviously parsing it).  However, the `Reports!rptParent!SubreportControl!lblTest.Visible` syntax you provided works like a champ!  I now have direct access to the control.  Also for posterity, the `Reports!rptTest!lblTest.Visible = True` syntax works when the report is opened directly.  Thank you!!!  :D

Comment: The only complication I could foresee is if I wanted the code to work in both subreport view as well as directly, in Report view (which I don't need here).  For my general fund of knowledge, is there perchance a way to detect (in OnLoad or OnOpen?) whether it's being loaded into a subreport control.  I could use that to control visibility of different versions of buttons, or (better) set a public var that governs which syntax to use.

Comment: OnLoad or OnOpen for the Report.  Can it detect that?

Comment: Check `CurrentProject.AllReports(Me.Name).IsLoaded` in `Report_Load()` ... it will be True when the report is opened directly as a "top-level" report, and False when it is "sort of open" as a subform/subreport control when its   parent form or report is opened.

Comment: Oops.  I should have known that.  :)  Thanks again!!